# How to install libXScrnSaver on openSUSE Leap 42.2

Tags: atom-editor, opensuse

I wanna install **Atom editor** on my laptop which is running **openSUSE Leap 42.2**, I use command `zypper in` to install the rpm package, but it prompts error info

> Problem: nothing provides **libXScrnSaver** needed by atom-1.12.6-0.1.x86_64

```
flying@lempstacker:~> sudo zypper in ~/Downloads/atom-1.12.6-0.1.x86_64.rpm 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libXScrnSaver needed by atom-1.12.6-0.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install atom-1.12.6-0.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break atom-1.12.6-0.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c):
```

The mirror official repositories I'm using were provided by [aliyun](http://mirrors.aliyun.com/help/opensuse), concrete configuration commands are

```
sudo zypper mr -da
sudo zypper rr `zypper repos | awk '{if(NR>2)print $5}'`
sudo zypper ar -fcg http://mirrors.aliyun.com/opensuse/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/oss/ 'Aliyun-Leap-42.2-OSS'
sudo zypper ar -fcg http://mirrors.aliyun.com/opensuse/distribution/leap/42.2/repo/non-oss/ 'Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Non-OSS'
sudo zypper ar -fcg http://mirrors.aliyun.com/opensuse/update/leap/42.2/oss/ 'Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-OSS'
sudo zypper ar -fcg http://mirrors.aliyun.com/opensuse/update/leap/42.2/non-oss/ 'Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-Non-OSS'
sudo zypper ref
```

exectue command `zypper repos`

```
flying@lempstacker:~> zypper repos
# | Alias                           | Name                            | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh
--+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------
1 | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Non-OSS        | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Non-OSS        | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes    
2 | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-OSS            | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-OSS            | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes    
3 | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-Non-OSS | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-Non-OSS | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes    
4 | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-OSS     | Aliyun-Leap-42.2-Update-OSS     | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes    
flying@lempstacker:~>
```

#### I tried to search `libXScrnSaver`

via command `zypper search`

```
flying@lempstacker:~> zypper search libXScrnSaver
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name                      | Summary                                                      | Type   
--+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------
  | libXScrnSaver-devel       | Development files for the X11 Screen Saver extension library | package
  | libXScrnSaver-devel-32bit | Development files for the X11 Screen Saver extension library | package
flying@lempstacker:~>
```

via command `zypper info`

```
flying@lempstacker:~> zypper info libXScrnSaver
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...


package 'libXScrnSaver' not found.
flying@lempstacker:~>
```

but it provided nothing except `libXScrnSaver-devel` which is not usefull even if I installed it.

#### I followed blog [Install Slack on openSUSE Leap 42.1](https://flanaras.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/install-slack-on-opensuse-leap-42-1/)

it says just need to install [libXss1](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libXss1), but it has been installed on my os.

```
flying@lempstacker:~> sudo zypper in libXss1
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libXss1' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'libXss1-1.2.2-11.19.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
flying@lempstacker:~>
```

I really want to know how to solve the problem!

#### Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat. Have you tried the option of 'breaking atom' by ignoring the dependencies?

I tried using this opensuse software page but I had no luck:
https://software.opensuse.org/package/libXScrnSaver

When I try to list installed packages I get a develop version:

```
linux-2472:/home/Downloads # rpm -qa | grep -i libxscr
libXScrnSaver-devel-1.2.2-11.19.x86_64
```

When I try to Install libXScrnSaver (version 1.2.2-10) I get:

```
linux-2472:/home/Downloads # zypper in ./libXScrnSaver-

1.2.2-10.1.src.rpm 
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'_tmpRPMcache_:libXScrnSaver=0:1.2.2-10.1' not found in package names. `Trying capabilities.`
No provider of '_tmpRPMcache_:libXScrnSaver=0:1.2.2-10.1' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Note that there are two versions in my link: 1.2.2-10.1 and 1.2.2-23.1 No Luck yet. maybe its that tmprpmcache_ package. I'll try tomorrow, it's late.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today on my opensuse 42.2 leap.
But choosing solution 2 (to install by ignoring dependencies) worked just fine.

Although according to this link here: 
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13354

The libXScrnSaver in not the one it actually wants, instead it requires libXss.so.1

Editing the spec file in the rpm was the solution suggested, although I have no idea how to do it.
This might help you : 
https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/13386

Answer (score 0):

It seems it'll be fixed in the upcoming release: https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/13386

I've just downloaded it and had the same problem. But I've installed it even breaking dependencies and it works without problems (be sure to have libXss installed):

```
sudo rpm -i --nodeps atom.x86_64.rpm
```